# Asana bad request when attempting to set custom field values (API)

Tags: python, python-requests, asana, zapier, asana-api

I am attempting to create a new task using the Asana API with https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks endpoint. I have been successful in creating some test tasks in the desired project. However I am now trying to also set the values of the custom fields and seem to be hitting a road block.

I am using the Python request library. I have a feeling this is an issue with the way I have formatted the post. I have checked a number of sources, including here, as well tinkered and modified the way in which I structure the "options" dictionary. However it does not seem to help.

```
def postTaskToAsana(taskName, taskURL, taskCreated, taskCompleted, taskDue):

token = "<TOKEN>"
bearerToken = "Bearer " + token
header = {
    "Authorization" : bearerToken
    }

options = {
    "projects" : ["234234234"],
    "name" : "Hello, World!",
    "notes" : "How are you",
    "assignee" : "2342342342",
    "custom_fields" : { "234234234234" : "hello" }
    }

url = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks"
r = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=options)
return r
```

If I remove the "custom_fields" from the options dictionary above then the post request works and I can see the newly created task. The response I get back from the above code is:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Oops! An unexpected error occurred while processing this request. The input may have contained something the server did not know how to handle. For more help, please contact api-support@asana.com and include the error phrase from this response.","phrase":"9 "}]}

As noted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271324/9237981) post the goal is to generate JSON for the request in this format:

```
{
"data" : {
    "custom_fields" : { "2342342342" : "INFO" }
    }
}
```

Which as far as I can tell is what my code should be doing.

Any help on this would be great, thanks.

Comment: If you have solved your problem then publish an answer and mark it as correct, you should not place SOLVED in the title.

Comment: If you solved your own question please post it as an answer and mark your own answer as the solution. This will help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RESOLVED]

As suspected the issue had to do with the way in which I was formatting my request. For reasons I am not clear on the additional level created by the nested custom_fields dictionary was not being formatted in correct JSON format. I was able to resolve this using requests JSON parameter.

```
def postTaskToAsana(taskName, taskURL, taskCreated, taskCompleted, taskDue):

token = "<TOKEN>"
bearerToken = "Bearer " + token
header = {
    "Authorization" : bearerToken
    }

options = {
    "data" : {
        "projects" : ["123412341234"],
        "name" : "Review Task: " + taskName,
        "notes" : "Please review this task for where the process failed.\nTask: " + taskURL,
        "assignee" : "123412341234",
        "followers" : ["123412341234"],
        "custom_fields" : {
            "123412341234" : taskCreated,
            "123412342134" : taskDue,
            "123412341234" : taskCompleted
        }
    }
}

url = "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks"
r = requests.post(url, headers=header, json=options)
return r
```